# What is the appropriate test for my Facebook project

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, correlation, chi-squared-test, conditional-probability

I have a little over 27,000 Facebook posts stored in a database. For each post, if the post has comments and replies, those are also stored in the database. The posts are from Facebook autism groups.

I am dividing the posts into what I call the scam era and the pre-scam era. The pre-scam era is the time period before 10/13/2019. The scam era is the time period from 10/13/2019 and going forward.

For each group, I aim to test for the following hypothesis- in the scam era, there is a shift in the content of the discussion of the group, where the discussion begins to increasingly be about mental disorders other than autism.

The way I intend to measure this is by doing an automated search for different mental health terms, like bipolar disorder, schizophrenia, schizoaffective disorder, etc.

I have my programming script already built and I have ran it on one group.I have a tally of the word count for 190 or so words, for each post, for one group.

The next step is to score each post, according to a scoring scheme. I give different point values to different mental health terms. I score each comment and comment reply separately as well.

I only took 2 semesters of statistics in college (I was a finance major), and I’m not sure what the appropriate test would be. My sample is huge and my chi square scores are thus astronomical and not usable.

Would a 1 tailed T test be appropriate here? Like say I score the pre-scam era month by month and do the same for the scam era, and use each set of scores to do the T test?

Comment: My first objection against a t-test would be that posts should probably not be treated as independent. Other than that, the problem with huge sample sizes in significance testing in general is that even very small and potentially irrelevant differences will come out significant (this may have happened to your chi-squared but also there independence of posts is required and  questionable). If you can make your case using appropriate data visualisation rather than hypothesis testing, that'd be good. Otherwise you might have to go into something far more complicated.

Comment: To clarify, I test each post and each post is assigned to its author in my database. What I’m testing is do the people who join on or after 10/13/2019 talk about mental disorders disproportionately, relative to the people before. I do the same with each comment and comment reply. 

My main posts table has 27,006 posts. I have loaded them on separate tables for each group. The group that I’m on now has 3557 posts, if I remember right. It’s something like that. I put the users in batches based on join dates, and I score the posts of each batch of users.

Comment: There is a related phenomenon where the groups that I am a member of (and some that I am not) get inundated with members after I join autism groups.  What I claim to have happened is a horde of people have been given the task of going in these autism groups and discussing mental disorders. I made a video series about it. 

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RhgTSpBYwO4&feature=youtu.be

That’s the first video. You can see how the members count skyrockets after I join.